# How to structure a multi-page website with Vue on each page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to use Vue on my first multi-page website and don't know how to split my code across pages. Let's say I have a "master" template which contains the headers and footer + 3 pages, Home, About and Contact.

If I have a single Vue instance in the master template I think I will need to have all the code for every page in that instance.

If I have a separate instance for each page then what do I do about shared code, e.g. a button in the header which launches a popup?

I can't really use Vue components with their own templates because all the pages have to have their HTML on page when it loads for SEO reasons (using asp.net Umbraco CMS).

Comment: You need to have the bundle file which includes `Vue` in your master page. Is there really any problem since I can not see one?

Comment: Not sure I can explain the problem any better than I have above really. If I have a single instance then how do I include the data/methods for the contact form only in a separate contact.js for example? Id I put everything in separate files how do I deal with data/methods etc. that need to be used in all pages?

Comment: Did you use vue-cli webpack template for your project? If not, how is your project setup?

Comment: If you have separate pages, then each page will have its own Vue instance.  Sharing data between pages will need to be done either through cookies or local storage (or saving state on the server via some kind of "session" and sending it to the client on each page load).

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I understand there will be a separate instance per page as the page is completely refreshed, but I'm wondering about the JS code that controls each page (in Angular you can attach a controller to any portion of the page). Some code will be shared on every page and some won't.